Map Vimeo Event URL to a Video ID?
My database contains URLs for Vimeo events, such as https://vimeo.com/event/452144x/eae7a2498x
I need the ID of the video associated with the event. Do either or both of the IDs in the event URL post to something in the Library or the list of videos I can use to correlate?
